# data transform of column by group into new columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

data as displayed

```
ID Group Type Var1 Var2
001   1   A   6.4   0.5
001   1   B   6.6   0.59
001   1   C   5.1   2.5
001   2   A   5.6   1.8
001   2   B   6.7   0.3
001   2   C   6.8   0.2
001   2   D   6.1   0.5

data <- data.frame(ID=rep("001", 7),
               Group=c(rep("1",3), rep("2", 4)),
               Type=c("A", "B", "C", "A","B", "C", "D"),
               Var1=runif(7, 5.0, 7.5),
               Var2=runif(7, 0, 2.5))
```

output

```
ID Group Var1_A Var2_A Var1_B Var2_B Var1_C Var2_C Var1_D Var2_D
001  1    6.4    0.5    6.6    0.59    5.1    2.5   NA      NA
001  2    5.6    1.8    6.7    0.3     6.8   0.2    6.1   0.5
```

I can do it in a slow way of 1) creating NA for all new variables; 2) fill it on condition if(Type=="A"){
Var1_A <- Var1
} else if(..)}
But I was wondering if there is a simple way of doing it with?

Comment: Could you try using `pivot_wider` from `library(tidyr)` such as: `pivot_wider(data, id_cols = c(ID, Group), names_from = Type, values_from = c(Var1, Var2))`?

Comment: Yes, it worked. thanks. I've found pivot long and pivot_wider a lot useful when reshaping the data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben suggested above, pivot_wider makes the data wider from matrix into vector and column name paste("Var", "Type", sep = '_')

```
library(tidyr)

data2<- pivot_wider(data, id_cols = c(ID, Group), names_from = Type, values_from = c(Var1, Var2))
```

output:

```
ID Group Var1_A Var1_B Var1_C Var1_D Var2_A Var2_B Var2_C  Var2_D 
001  1    6.4    6.6    5.1     NA    0.5    0.59   2.5     NA
001  2    5.6    6.7    6.8    6.1    1.8    0.3    0.2     0.5
```